# Azure Stream Analytics · Counting people in/out from a room

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics

I'm trying to make a query in Stream Analytics in order to send the output to PowerBI.

I need three things:

- Counting people (location=Entrada - location=Salida). That is the load factor of the room, the people that has entered minus people has left the room.
- Show the % capacity (100 people max in the room)
- Evolution line

I'm new to Stream Analytics queries, I find it quite complicated.

This is my IoT Hub input dataset:

[image]

And this is my query:

```sql
    SELECT System.Timestamp AS WindowEnd,
           COUNT(*)
    INTO [output-pbi]
    FROM [input-rfid]
        GROUP BY HoppingWindow(second,3600,1)
```

In this example, I need to show that there is 1 person in the room (1% of total capacity) and a evolution line similar as this (always in real time):

[image]

I don't know if I'm using the correct Window function.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Could you explain about `counting people`? Is it like count of rows with location="Entrada" minus count of rows with location="Salida"?

Comment: Hi, Aswin. That'`s right, 'counting people' must be the people that has entered the room minus people that has left the room. In other words, the load factor of the room. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the query below for getting the results you expected.

```sql
WITH CountPeople AS (
    SELECT
        System.Timestamp AS WindowEnd,
        COUNT(*) AS PeopleCount, location
    FROM [input1]
    WHERE location = 'Entrada' OR location = 'Salida'
    GROUP BY HoppingWindow(minute, 1, 1), location
)

SELECT
    CP.WindowEnd,
    SUM(CASE WHEN CP.location = 'Entrada' THEN CP.PeopleCount ELSE 0 END) -
    SUM(CASE WHEN CP.location = 'Salida' THEN CP.PeopleCount ELSE 0 END) AS LoadFactor,
    (SUM(CASE WHEN CP.location = 'Entrada' THEN CP.PeopleCount ELSE 0 END) -
    SUM(CASE WHEN CP.location = 'Salida' THEN CP.PeopleCount ELSE 0 END))*100/100 AS CapacityPercentage
INTO [output1]
FROM CountPeople CP
GROUP BY CP.WindowEnd, TumblingWindow(second, 1)
```

Here, I am getting `CountPeople` every second for the past 1 minute, grouped by the locations.

Then, I am taking the difference between the records with location `Entrada` and `Salida`.

Output:

[image]

Again, you need to alter the query according to your data, like `UID`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind reply and SQL code. I have tried it, it works partially, the evolution line (X: WindowEnd, X: loadfactor) does strange things. I have tried this code and it seems to work, but I have doubts with the HoppingWindow function (maybe it's not the best option): SELECT System.Timestamp AS WindowEnd,
                  SUM(CASE WHEN location = 'Entrada' THEN 1 
                                      WHEN location = 'Salida' THEN -1 ELSE 0 END) AS Ocupacion,     INTO [output-pbi] FROM [input-rfid] GROUP BY HoppingWindow(second,3600,10)

Comment: You need select the window function based on your data stream. How frequently you need the data or in what interval you need load factor. Based on that you need to choose.